# Cannot install httr package in R 3.6.2 in Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: r, rstudio, linux-mint, r-package, httr

I am totally new to R.

I tried to install the **httr** package.

I first installed pacman, and then tried to load httr through it by running `pacman::p_load(httr)`.

It wasn't successful. And it showed the following message in terminal-

> Installing package into
>   ‘/home/|username|/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’
>
> trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.3.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 673779 bytes (657 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 657 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/openssl_1.4.1.tar.gz' Content
>   type 'application/x-gzip' length 1206885 bytes (1.2 MB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 1.2 MB
>
> trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_1.4.1.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 158465 bytes (154 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 154 KB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
>     ** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** using staged installation Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>     containing `libcurl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No
>     package 'libcurl' found Package libcurl was not found in the
>     pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>     containing`libcurl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No
>     package 'libcurl' found Using PKG_CFLAGS= Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
>     ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR --------------------------- Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:  *
>     deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  * rpm: libcurl-devel
>     (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)  * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris) If libcurl is
>     already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and
>     PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config is
>     unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD
>     INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
>     -------------------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
> - removing ‘/home/|username|/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/curl’
> - installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
>     ** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** using staged installation Using PKG_CFLAGS=
>     ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR --------------------------- Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:  *
>     deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora,
>     CentOS, RHEL)  * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)  * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac
>     OSX) If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in
>     your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If
>     pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually
>     via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
>     -------------------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
> - removing ‘/home/|username|/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/openssl’ ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package
>     ‘httr’
> - removing ‘/home/|username|/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/httr’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/Rtmp3wZaOu/downloaded_packages’ Warning messages: 1: In
>   utils::install.packages(package, ...) :   installation of package
>   ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status 2: In utils::install.packages(package,
>   ...) :   installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status 3:
>   In utils::install.packages(package, ...) :   installation of package
>   ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status 4: In p_install(package,
>   character.only = TRUE, ...) :  5: In library(package, lib.loc =
>   lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :   there is
>   no package called ‘httr’ 6: In pacman::p_load(httr) : Failed to
>   install/load: httr

How do I solve this?

Note: I have installed several other external packages through pacman. Like- dplyr, ggplot2 etc.

Comment: The `httr` pacakge has system dependencies as described in the error that R cannnot install for you. Have you installed the curl development libraries on your system? Something like `sudo apt-get libcurl4-openssl-dev` or whatever the equivalent for the Mint distribution is. Also needs: `sudo apt-get libssl-dev`

Comment: @MrFlick it worked. I installed **OpenSSL** and **Libcurl-dev** on my system. Then opened R Studio and tried to install **curl**. But it said I had to get "BiocManager". I installed it, and then successfully installed **curl**. I was also having problem with **rio** apart from **httr** and **curl**. All installations went down smooth. Thanks. PS. I also had to get **libssl-dev** from [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libssl-dev).

Comment: @MrFlick  I ran into the same problem when trying to install the "httr" package in R in a container created using the r-base Docker official image. My `install.packages("httr", dependencies = TRUE)` spat three ANTICONF ERRORs, complaining that "libcurl4-openssl-dev", "libssl-dev" and "libxml2-dev" were missing. I therefore installed these three packages from the terminal using `sudo apt install`. `apt list` confirmed that they'd been installed, but then installation of "httr" still failed with the three ANTICONF ERRORs. Do you see what went wrong?

Comment: @elarry Did you install them in the docker container or on your primary OS? Cause those would need to be in the container. If you have troubles, you should probably open your own question with the contents of your dockerfile to more easily diagnose the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick Ah! I installed them on my primary OS! I'm a newbie to Linux and Docker so haven't realised this. I hadn't used a Dockerfile, but simply ran the r-base image to test whether the R packages I needed could be installed in the container. It took me quite a while to go through various Q&As online but I was still confused. Thanks very much for your quick and helpful answer. I'll give it a go and open my own question if I can't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`httr` imports `openssl` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openssl/index.html) and `curl` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html)
and both are specific system requirements. For `openssl` "SystemRequirements:   OpenSSL >= 1.0.1" and for `curl` "SystemRequirements:   libcurl: libcurl-devel (rpm) or libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb)."