# R and libcurl4 hardly coexist in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, curl, httr

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I recently upgraded my R version from `3.2.3` to `3.6.3`. Upon reinstallation of the packages that I need, I stumbled upon an issue generated by [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) and [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html). Other posts, especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287025/cannot-install-httr-package-in-r-3-6-2-in-linux-mint-19-3) (but also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118202/installing-libcurl4-removes-r-packages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686470/install-curl-and-readr-on-r)) have been written about similar (if not almost identical issues) but following them led me nowhere and my issue is still there.

I'm sorry in advance for the long post, but I think that other people will eventually stumble upon this issue so I want to be as complete as possible. Here's what happens.

I am trying to install a package that has `httr` among the dependencies. Since I need to reinstall it, I tried to do so from `install.packages("httr")` and from a local path (see example).

```
> install.packages("/home/schmat/Documents/Marti/packages/httr_1.4.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/home/schmat/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
```

This showed me that `curl` is not available, so I tried to install `curl` the same way. Only to get this:

```
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since this showed that I needed to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, I tried to do it via `apt install` and I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried to add the `libcurl.pc` file that I have to `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```sh
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/schmat/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
```

Without any result.

I tried the `git clone` approach suggested in [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754294), without any success.

At this point, I tried to install `libcurl4` from `apt install`. However, by doing so my R gets *removed* from the system. I reinstalled R (same version, 3.6.3) and this removes `libcurl4`.

I am stuck in this loop where I can't get what I need because something else is missing, in a circle. How is that possible? How come, that an R package (latest version, March 26, 2020!) which ultimately needs some `curl` function cannot be installed, because `curl` cannot coexist with `R/3.6.3`?

Comment: I often had problems with `curl` after upgrading `R`. There are several `curl` flavors, though. I'm using `R` 3.6.3 with libs `libcurl4` and `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` (on Lubuntu 18.4). What do you get when you call `dpkg -l | grep curl`?

Comment: I fixed it! (see my own answer)

`ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64                      7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8                                   amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)` and 
`ii  libcurl4:amd64                             7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8                                   amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)` and 
`ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64                 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8                                   amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)`

Answer (score 0):

It's incredible how, after days of trial and error, the very moment I decided to write a question here I also found the answer minutes later.

In one of the links I provided ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118202/installing-libcurl4-removes-r-packages)), OP mentions that he/she cleaned the `/etc/apt/sources.list` from "rubbish". It is not, however, declared which rubbish or how the file was edited.

what I did (and worked) for me was the following.

1. I edited the file (with sudo rights) changing the last two lines from:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

To:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ bionic-cran35/
deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ bionic-cran35/
```

Note that I changed "xenial" to "bionic", and I uncommented the last line.

3. Closed and re-opened the terminal.
4. Ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
5. Installed **libcurl4** via `sudo apt install -y libcurl4`. This still uninstalls **R** and its components.
6. Installed **libcurl4-openssl-dev** via `sudo apt install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev`.
7. Ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
8. Installed **r-base** via `sudo apt install -y r-base`. This time, `libcurl4` is not uninstalled.
9. Run `R`, and install the package that I needed.